# wmode = opaque not working for object in IE 10 on Win 8

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, wmode

I am having this issue with embedding a video using 
If adding:

```
<param name="wmode" value="opaque">
```

the video player is not displayed in IE 10 on Windows 8.

It is working well on Windows 8 with other browsers, the only problem is with IE. Also, it works fine on Windows 7 with IE 10 and IE 11. Also, if value for wmode is "direct" or "window", video player is displayed ok.

So, can anyone tell me if there is a solution for this?
Thanks.

Comment: are you using the APP for IE on W8 or the desktop client?

Comment: I use it for Desktop client

Comment: and what happens if you do it via the app?

Answer (score 0):

Ok this might sound stupid, but I just had some problem with Wmode="transparent" in windows 8 IE11 that wasn't a problem before I installed IE11.

I got the problem solved by writing transparent with a cap T (Wmode="Transparent"), so maybe writing opaque with a cap O (Opaque) would help...

Just a suggestion